# DJI-SDK retrieve x,y Coordinates accurately. GPS is too inaccurate

Tags: coordinates, augmented-reality, hololens, android-gps, dji-sdk

I am trying to create an application with AR that will display objects hovering right on top of the drone to help the user flying experience (e.g. show an arrow or gimbals on your AR-goggles that follow the drone and shows where the drone is and its attitude when it is far away).
For this I need the X and Y coordinates of the drone to be able to place the arrow on top of the drone when the drone moves around. However the GPS coordinates returned by the drone through the SDK are only accurate to 1.5m or worse.
Is there any better way to determine the drones position? Or retrieve some x and y values through the dji mobile sdk?
I am using a DJI Mini 2 and Micrososft HoloLens2 goggles.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nop you can't get better position info.
You need a RTK drone to do that.

I don't understand why you cant do with 2m accuracy? If it's 50meter away, 1m error wont do that much?